# Does GUID change on update?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, guid, updates

So I am getting the GUID number and using it in my application for some stuff and checking processes with database. But I don't know whether the GUID stays the same or changes on updates, because if it changes - I will have to rewrite parts of the program, and I don't want to do that.

I mean - I have already published and given the product to the client (with some GUID), but after some time I make some changes to the software, and provide it as update of the product, to the client. Does the GUID change then or it stays the same?

Comment: No. It doesn't change. It stays the same.

Comment: @Prash - does it depend on (connected with) the project, the solution or smth else ?
Thanks for the quick answer! :)

Comment: if you are you talking about the guid in assembly info then yes, it does not change automatically.

Comment: @Syspect - Just see my answer below. It is a assembly (exe/dll) related thing (implies, a project related thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It doesn't change. Actually, the significance of the GUID comes into picture if the assembly is made `COMVisible`. `AssemblyInfo.cs` file gets generated at the time the project is created. And GUID in that doesn't change automatically.

Comment: if i run a for loop and inside it i create 10 guid. and then recompile the project and run it, the same guids will be genmerated again? So the first for example 10 guids a project is genberating, no matter where or how they are generated, will alwyas be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on how big the update is... I would say no, it do not change... If we are talking about product GUID it should change on release of new version of products...

take a look at http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization